# Is there a way to tag specific class methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically, I have a class with methods, some of which I would like to label with their category. For example:

```
class ExampleClass:
    # category: foo
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""

    # category: foo
    def method_b(self):
        """does stuff"""

    def method_c(self):
        """does stuff"""

    # category: bar
    def method_d(self):
        """does stuff"""

    # category: foo
    def method_e(self):
        """does stuff"""
```

Now I want to write a separate function which will look through the class's namespace and return the names of all methods that are labeled with a specific category. (Say, for example, because I wanted to run all methods with a specific tag.)

```
def find_methods(class, label):
    """Searches through the class namespace
       returns all methods with the correct label"""
```

For example, this is the output that would be desired:

```
find_methods(ExampleClass, 'foo')
# Returns ['method_a', 'method_b', 'method_e']

find_methods(ExampleClass, 'bar')
# Returns ['method_d']

find_methods(ExampleClass, 'baz')
# Returns []
```

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to implement this.

The manual thing to do would be to just maintain a list of method names and categories in a variable defined at the top of the class, but that requires a lot of upkeep because every time I add a new method I have to remember to update my list. It also gets really confusing if I have a class that inherits from ExampleClass that also has tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Better solution, see explanation below section below.

Depending on you needs it may be resonable to do not search through `dir` of class and all it attributes on every `find_methods` call. It this is a case I would make tagging function more smart and build list of tagged function as you add them and store into dictionary. Find_methods would simply retreive function list from dictionary then.

E.g

```
class Tagger(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._dict = {}

  def __call__(self, name):
    if name not in self._dict:
      self._dict[name] = []
    def tags_decorator(func):
      self._dict[name].append(func)
      func._tag = name
      return func
    return tags_decorator

tag = Tagger()
class ExampleClass:
  @tag('foo')
  def method_a(self):
    """does stuff"""

  @tag('foo')
  def method_b(self):
    """does stuff"""

  def method_c(self):
    """does stuff"""

  @tag('bar')
  def method_d(self):
    """does stuff"""

  @tag('bar')
  def method_e(self):
    """does stuff"""

print(tag._dict)
```

ORIGINAL POST: Explanation of final solution.

I'll extend idea which was given by someone else, but got deleted. He proposed to add to every function private attribute `_tag`. You can do it, as everything in Python is an object.

So:

```
class ExampleClass:
    # category: foo
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""
    method_a._tag = "foo"
```

It is dirty code though, so maybe we can do better? E.g. lets wrap tagging with function.

```
def add_foo_tag(func):
    func._tag = "foo"
    return func

class ExampleClass:
    # category: foo
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""
    method_a = add_foo_tag(method_a)
```

But we can still do better: there is decorators syntax `@` for that, which will call `method_a = add_foo_tag(method_a)` for us:

```
class ExampleClass:
    # category: foo
    @add_foo_tag
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""
```

But what with other tag strings? Let's create tag decorator factory!

```
def tag(tag_name):
    def tags_decorator(func):
        func._tag = tag_name
        return func
    return tags_decorator
```

And syntax is nice:

```
class ExampleClass:
    @tag('foo')
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('foo')
    def method_b(self):
        """does stuff"""

    def method_c(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('bar')
    def method_d(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('bar')
    def method_e(self):
        """does stuff"""
```

Now, what with finding the methods in class? There is `dir` operation which we can use. There is an explicit version of code:

```
def find_methods_explicit(cls, label):
  """Searches through the class namespace
     returns all methods with the correct label"""
     attributes = [getattr(cls, func) for func in dir(cls)]
     tagged = [attr for attr in attributes if '_tag' in dir(atrr)]
     labeled = [attr for attr in tagged if  atrr._tag == label]
     return labeled
```

And one-liner:

```
def find_methods(cls, label):
    """Searches through the class namespace
        returns all methods with the correct label"""
    return [getattr(cls, func) for func in dir(cls) if '_tag' in dir(getattr(cls, func)) and getattr(cls, func)._tag == label]
```

Finally, usage:

```
print(ExampleClass.method_a._tag)    
print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'foo'))
print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'bar'))
print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'qwe'))
```

Full code:

```
def tag(tag_name):
    def tags_decorator(func):
        func._tag = tag_name
        return func
    return tags_decorator

class ExampleClass:
    @tag('foo')
    def method_a(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('foo')
    def method_b(self):
        """does stuff"""

    def method_c(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('bar')
    def method_d(self):
        """does stuff"""

    @tag('bar')
    def method_e(self):
        """does stuff"""

def find_methods(cls, label):
    """Searches through the class namespace
        returns all methods with the correct label"""
    return [getattr(cls, func) for func in dir(cls) if '_tag' in dir(getattr(cls, func)) and getattr(cls, func)._tag == label]

print(ExampleClass.method_a._tag)

print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'foo'))
print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'bar'))
print(find_methods(ExampleClass,'qwe'))
```

And online example: https://repl.it/repls/FrayedMilkyKangaroo

Answer (score 0):

```
for method_name in dir(ExampleClass):
   if callable(getattr(ExampleClass, method_name)):
       print(method_name)
```

EDIT

In a function, this would be.

```
def find_methods(classobj, label):
    for method_name in dir(classobj):
       if method_name == label:
           if callable(getattr(classobj, method_name)):
               print(method_name)
```

Comment: This function checks if the method name is equal to a specific name. What I care about is whether the method name is tagged with something that has a specific name. The method name itself can be whatever.

Comment: how often do the tags change? @K.Mao

Comment: Very infrequently, if ever. As I said before, I could include a variable at the top of the class that maps between methods and tags. However this is more difficult to maintain, and gets especially messy if I am inheriting from ExampleClass and have additional tags in the child class.

Comment: if you maybe included the tag at the end of the method name, that may be able to work for you. such as method_a_foo and then do "if method_name.endswith(label): #do stuff @K.Mao

Answer (score 0):

You could (mis)use type annotations:

```
def f(args) -> "category":
    # code

 f_category = f.__annotations__.get('return') # None if no category defined
```

Or you could use function attributes:

```
def f(args):
    # code

f.category = "category"

f_category = f.category
```

And for `find_methods`:

```
def find_methods(class, label):
    for name in dir(class):
        possible_method = getattr(class, name)
        # test if it has the right label and is a function
        yield name # or append to a list and return
```

Comment: I'll have to play around with it, but I assume that function attributes are along the lines of what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'd look at the other answer if you want to do that, it goes into more detail than this.